# WebClient DownloadString causes sometimes "object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient, nullreferenceexception

In my C# program I am using WebClient to download a string which works fine in general, but from time to time I get the exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

The following example shows the relevant part of the code:

```
String ResponseString = "";
String URITarget = "..... my URI information .....";

using (WebClient WebClientInstance = new WebClient())
{

    WebClientInstance.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    WebClientInstance.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    ResponseString = WebClientInstance.DownloadString(URITarget);

}
```

The exception happens at this code line:

```
ResponseString = WebClientInstance.DownloadString(URITarget);
```

As I am using threads and therefore the function with the above code can be called theoretically at the same time from different threads, I first thought the problem could be caused by the threads as WebClient is not thread-safe. But after implementing lock(SendWebClientHTTPRequestThreadLock) around the above code, it did not bring any improvement:

```
private Object SendWebClientHTTPRequestThreadLock = new Object();

...


String ResponseString = "";
String URITarget = "..... my URI information .....";

lock (SendWebClientHTTPRequestThreadLock)
{

    using (WebClient WebClientInstance = new WebClient())
    {

        WebClientInstance.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        WebClientInstance.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        ResponseString = WebClientInstance.DownloadString(URITarget);

    }

}
```

Can it be that WebClientInstance.DownloadString(URITarget) returns NULL for some reason instead the actual or at least an empty string? Any suggestions?

Comment: The code as posted cannot throw a `NullReferenceException` except somewhere buried in the implementation of `DownloadString`. Please post the entire stack trace and preferrably give us a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/), beyond what you think is relevant.

Comment: It's not `WebClientInstance.DownloadString(URITarget)` that returns NULL. It seems that `WebClientInstance` itself is `null` for some reason and therefore you cannot call any method of it.

Comment: I added some more logic to my application to improve the analysis of the problem. Unfortunately (or fortunately?), the problem did not appear again since last week. I keep monitoring the situation and will come up with further details as soon as available.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your WebClientInstance object gets nullified before the using block is terminated is odd. I am guessing that it might be related to a resource issue or a memory leak in you application. Maybe you are hitting the limits of the thread pool and your threads are getting terminated abruptly because of that.

I would also try the non-blocking methods of the WebClient, such as WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync, and see if that makes a difference. If that doesn't solve the issue I would try using the TPL instead of raw threads for safe thread pool management.

Comment: It's more than *odd* -- it is, by the language standard and all practical compiler implementations, *impossible*. If the constructor call doesn't throw, the result will be non-`null`. SInce no assignment occurs to the variable it cannot become `null`. The runtime will not suddenly nullify variables, no matter what's happening with resources. We can conclude that "the `WebClientInstance` object [getting] nullified" is supremely unlikely. It's far more likely the OP has left out relevant details. What you're suggesting by guessing is shotgun debugging, which almost never works.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was just kindly referring to the comment that was posted as a response to you above... The issue could be anything of course, but since the OP cannot post the entire application here we have to take an iterative approach and start from somewhere or throw our hands up in the sky and dismiss the question...

Comment: You can post a comment as an answer if (and only if) you don't yet have the reputation to comment, but then it helps if you make it clear in the text that that's what you're doing. Trying to improve the question is fine, but that's not what answers are for.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I'll certainly need that being a few hours old on the site...

Answer (score 0):

Probably is about security issue. Some hosts need to authenticate in order to allow read stream. Check remote server for error (403) Forbidden.
In this case you need to pass username and password to get access to the file.

Comment: This could be a comment..!!